# Why doesn't MoveBy work in this example?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'd like to run an action on a sprite using the MoveBy action. After lots of attempts, I can't achieve the goal... I have issues with the MoveBy in 2 different projects, so maybe I'm missing something in the setup... But I can't figure what!

The instruction is like this:

```
this.platform1Sprite.runAction(cc.MoveBy.create(1, cc.p(200, 0)));
```

I don't get any error, simply it doesn't work. platform1Sprite is a Sprite. But even with a LabelTTF it doesn't work:

```
var MoveToAction = cc.MoveTo.create(2.5, cc.p(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
this.creditLabel.runAction(MoveToAction);
```

For this last snippet, you can view my complete code here: http://pastebin.com/fGbW4LLH.

The code I linked is somehow similar to the [helloHTML5World official example](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/blob/master/HelloHTML5World/src/myApp.js), line 112 has the runAction method applied to a LabelTTF. The official example works, mine doesn't... I can't understand what's the difference!

Comment: The code works for me. Is platform1Sprite a cc.Sprite?

Comment: Yes, it is. In the official [COCOS2D-x forum](http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/19/topics/16376) they also said the code works. But I'm sure it doesn't! In the link to the forum there's the full code of a project that doesn't work. I'm using FF16, but even with Chrome it doesn't work (in 2 different computers). Suggestions?

Comment: If you put your code into http://pastebin.com and link me, I will be glad to look it over for you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fGbW4LLH
Lines 17 and 18 have the MoveTo action!

Comment: are you sure you are not disabling schedule manager somewhere by mistake?

Comment: I don't even know how to do that! The code in pastebin.com is the FULL code of my project (I'm just developing some examples for my own use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem! :)

In "credits.js" you need to change:

```
onEnter:function() {    
},

onExit: function() {
},
```

to

```
onEnter:function() {
    this._super();      
},

onExit: function() {
    this._super();
},
```

Hope this works for you!

-Edit-
The reason actions were not running is because 1) the engine was not being notified of any of the objects in the layer and 2) the scheduler/actions were not being resumed for said layer.

*CCNode.js*'s onEnter( ), called through *CCLayer.js*'s onEnter( ):

```
onEnter:function () {
    this._isRunning = true;//should be running before resumeSchedule
    this._arrayMakeObjectsPerformSelector(this._children, cc.Node.StateCallbackType.onEnter);
    this.resumeSchedulerAndActions();
},
```

Comment: Thank you... Unfortunately your solution seems wrong. Either the first snippet and the one after the EDIT don't work...
Anyway, if you look at the [HelloHTM5World](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/blob/master/HelloHTML5World/src/myApp.js) official example there's nothing similar to what you posted... And that example works! Look at line 112 for LabelTTF's runAction method.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I zipped the code I used here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3a1he4kdwel7k0h/cocos2dhtml5code.zip   
It was built from your pastebin code and it works in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Also, if you delete the onEnter and onExit functions the code works. That's how the official example is coded; without the functions.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The pastebin code referred to a slight different project. And without the onEnter and onExit methods (or using the super definition) it works.
But the original project, that's here http://pastebin.com/bjNKcznE, didn't work with the line 167 uncommented... What if I want to schedule update??? I can't figure why it doesn't work! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: to schedule an update: in your init add "this.schedule(this.update);" then have a function like: "update:function (delta){},"